# Can I use GeoSPARQL without importing the ontology

Tags: postgis, geometry, geosparql

I am building my ontology and i defined the data property :hasGeometry in my ontology and mapped it to geom column in the database. I didn't import the GeoSPARQL ontology. Can I in this case use GeoSPARQL functions?